# Why is the page refreshing after I add an item to the To Do list?

Tags: forms, append, createelement

I just learned how to create and append items. I wanted to practice using a button to submit the text to be appended. It works, however, the page seems to refresh right afterwards and removes the text from the list. What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>To Do List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ToDo.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>To Do:</h1>
    <ul>
        <li class="todo">Create another todo.</li>
    </ul>

    <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Add another item!">
        <button onclick="output()">Add</button>
    </form>

    <script src="ToDo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
let ul = document.querySelector('ul');

newItem = document.querySelector('input');

function output() {
    let item = newItem.value;
    let newTodo = document.createElement('li');
    newTodo.innerText = item;
    newTodo.classList.add('todo');
    ul.append(newTodo);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button is submitting the form which is causing the page to refresh. Buttons are made to be type `submit` by default.

It looks like you don't actually need the form so you could either remove it or set the type on the button:

```
<button type="button" onclick="output()">Add</button>
```